# Prove that $h_n(x) g_n(x) $ uniformly converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I need some clue on the following proof:

let $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continous and not identically zero

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x) = f(0) = 0$

define: $h_n(x) = f(\frac{x}{n})$

$g_n(x) = f(nx)$

Prove that ${h_n}{g_n}$ uniformly converges.

Thanks :)

Comment: $f$ shell be not zero for all $x$ but also $f(0) = 0$… that makes no sense…

Answer (score 0):

From $f$ continuous and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0$ we know that $f$ is uniformly bounded on $[0,\infty)$. Says $|f|<M$.

Using  $f(0)=0$, then for any $\varepsilon>0$ we can find $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)|<\varepsilon$ on $[0,\delta)$.

Now, for any given $\varepsilon>0$ choose $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $|f(x)|<\varepsilon$ for $x\in[0,\frac 1m)\cup[m,\infty)$. Consider 
$$
h_m(x)g_m(x)=f(\frac xm)\cdot f(mx)<
\begin{cases}
\varepsilon\cdot M\ ;\ x<1 \\
M \cdot \varepsilon\ ;\ 1 \le x.
\end{cases}
$$
This shows that $h_m(x)g_m(x)<\varepsilon M$ for all $x\in [0,\infty)$. It shouldn't be hard for you to complete the rest of the argument to show that $h_ng_n\to 0$ uniformly as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Is it enough to show that gn and hn converges pointwise to 0 to complete?

Comment: Apparently no, if I understand you correctly. What you need is that for any given $\varepsilon>0$ you can find $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $\sup|h_m(x)g_m(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $m\ge n$.